# Creating a maven repository that downloads and stores jars from another maven repository

Tags: maven, ivy

We have a maven repository setup on a computer (host is `http://repository:8280`). Jars are uploaded to the repository and we use IVY to pull relevant jars for development.
We have an office in another country,  many miles from the repository server. It takes a lot of time to download jars. I want to setup another server closer to the other office which when a jar is uploaded to `http://repository:8280` it also gets uploaded to this new repository. Like a mirrored repository or something.

Can this be done and if so is there any tutorials online?

Comment: Do you use the [Repository Manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html)?

Comment: Yes. I am using Maven repository Manager

Comment: I'm using the simple and stupid step by creating another Repository Manager at the remote site, with the same configuration, e.g. point to maven central and so on. Then I point it back to our center repository only for our artifacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what Maven repository manager you are using.

The use case you've outlined is supported by the [Nexus repository manager](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), the following diagram describes its [smart proxy feature](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/smartproxy.html):

[image]